# How to constrain all user mode processes to access physical memory only in specific range?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, virtual-memory

How to constrain all user mode processes to access physical memory only in specific range?

So user page table mappings has to be constrained to a specific physical region defined by starting address and ending address (or the size). Yes, can be done by numactl and libnuma at node granularity. However, we need finer granularity. We need to do it inside the linux kernel.

Comment: ... I'm honestly not sure what you're hoping to accomplish. This might be an XY problem.

Comment: You are so not helpful...

Comment: You did not ask a very helpable question. Try explaining what you are actually trying to accomplish, and maybe we'll be able to tell you how better to go about it.

Comment: I need to direct memory accesses to specific range, preferably correlated with a DRAM DIMM range or DRAM channel (assuming channel interleaving is off in BIOS). This would increase memory pressure on specific physical memory device. After that I would need to implement page migration algorithm and migrate pages to another DIMM or channel. This is basically for modeling / prototyping a hardware memory system.

Comment: ... You're probably going to have to rewrite significant chunks of the memory subsystem of the linux kernel, because the whole point of the subsystem (in pretty much every OS, frankly) is to abstract memory access away from the where the user has to worry about it. Questions on how to go about that are well beyond the scope of this site, and tend to be on the level of "if you have to ask this, you don't know enough to start" That said, good luck with your endeavors.

Comment: The best you can do without hacking up the kernel would be to use the sys interface to deactivate certain memory units.